# How to APPEND, NOT REPLACE transition value?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Say I have got a `<div></div>`

In stylesheet file I got (in `sass`)

```
div
  transition: border-color linear 1s
```

It works fine of course

then I want some of div got `height` in their `transition-property`, depends on class, so I got some `<div class='changeheight'></div>`, and In stylesheet file:

```
div.changeheight
  transition: height linear 1s
```

and then, only the second transition rule works, the first transition rule suddenly be replaced, or say, got strikethrough in chrome dev tool.

So how can I make these two rules work together?

Comment: you need to add both animations comma separated in the .changeheight class, and probably rename it for heightAndBorder so it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transition two properties, you'll have to have them together in a comma separated list, otherwise the last rule will overwrite the previous rules.

I would suggest using specific classes for the different transitions, like `.bordered` and `.changeheight` which you can then combine the transition, like so:

```
.bordered {
  transition: border-color linear 1s;
}

.changeheight {
  transition: height linear 1s;
}

.bordered.changeheight {
  transition: border-color linear 1s, height linear 1s;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just `transition: all linear 1s;` to have every animatable property transition smoothly.